# jQuery UI - Autocomplete source dependent from selected option in different input

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to use Autocomplete script from jquery-ui.min.js. So in code I have:

```
<select id="country"><option value="">Choice one</option>
<option value="1">US</option>
<option value="2">UK</option></select>
<input type="text" id="city" >
```

And the script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var US= ["City1", "City2", "City3"];
  var UK= ["UK_City1", "UK_City2", "UK_City3"];
  $("#city").autocomplete({  
  source: US  
  });
}); 
</script>
```

The question is how to change source dependent on user selected text from Select ID="Country"? Here is also this script: http://jsbin.com/adopo3/35/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to use [option method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#methods) to change the source. I have modified your example code to illustrate it [here](http://jsbin.com/evibom/7/edit#preview).

Another way would be to supply callback function to the source option. See that [here](http://jsbin.com/evibom/8/edit#preview)

Comment: This is working fine, but what to do if I have more than two options in my Select, eg.`<option value="3">France-south</option><option value="4">France-north</option>` and more vars?